# Setting PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME using Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to set my `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME` variables but can't figure it out!

When trying to run `python`, I get the error `No module named site`.

After doing some research, it seems that this is because these `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME` environment variables are not set correctly.

When I try to run `python` after unsetting both of these variables, it is able to run properly. But the problem is that this only lasts for the life of my `virtualenv`. After I stop the `virtualenv` and run it again, the problem comes back.

Well I'm saying `virtualenv`, but really it's my environment on Heroku.

How do I unset these variables permanently?

---

Update: I followed the [tutorial here](http://tomatohater.com/2012/01/17/custom-django-management-commands-on-heroku/) which seemed to do the trick.

Comment: If `PYTHONPATH` is not set properly, this is probably more of a Heroku problem than a Python one, figure out what `PYTHONPATH` should be, and check Heroku's configuration docs on how to set it: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: You could try dynamically setting your `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME` so that it's set every time the program is run.

Comment: I don't feel like we have enough information to answer this question. You didn't show us a stacktrace, or respond to the "answer" saying you need to figure out what values those variables have. Perhaps someone can infer from your update link a decent answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reference from the [blog post](http://tomatohater.com/2012/01/17/custom-django-management-commands-on-heroku/) mentioned as the solution:

> On Heroku, your home directory is generally "/app". You should confirm
>   this by running:
>
> ```sh
> $ heroku run env | grep HOME
> HOME=/app
> ```
>
> A simple way to adjust your Python path within your Heroku environment (and not mucking with your app) is by setting the PYTHONPATH env variable as follows:
>
> ```sh
> $ heroku config:add PYTHONPATH=/app
> ```
>
> To confirm it is set correctly,
>   run:
>
> ```sh
> $ heroku run env | grep PYTHONPATH
> PYTHONPATH=/app
> ```
>
> Now you can run your custom management command. This also allows you to run these as cron (scheduled) tasks:
>
> ```sh
> $ heroku run python your_app/manage.py your_custom_command
> Success!
> ```

Note that adding to (or creating) the PythonPath is valid for most Python environments, not just Heroku, but you will need to determine how to add to it for your given environment.

One way to do this is to add a `PYTHONPATH` variable to your local user or system environment. Read more about `PYTHONPATH`, `PYTHONHOME`, and other [Python-related environment variables in the Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonpath#environment-variables).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do that?.

In Heroku when you select the python Buildpacks those variables are set automatic and you can run any python script from Heroku CLI in your dyno.

Answer (score -2):

> When trying to run python, I get the error No module named site.
>   After doing some research, it seems that this is because these PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME environment variables are not set correctly.

That sounds like the right answer. You need to figure out *what values* those variables have at the time, what values they *should* have, and what existing procedure in your environment is *setting* those variables to the wrong values.

All of that can only be answered by inspecting your environment, so good luck :-)